# Using AJAX to write a paragraph tag into an html page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Basically I have two files, one is **HTML** and the other is a simple file called `ajax_access_database.php` but it's not really accessing any database (that was my first plan but then I ran into problems). What I was hoping for was to use a JavaScript function called `OUTPUT()` to place a paragraph tag with ***Hello World*** inside it but I can't seem to properly make the **PHP** call within the `OUTPUT()` function, or maybe it's something else. I've checked all over but **PHP** is very strange with its syntax and integrating it into another language is even more confusing.

This is the `ajax_access_database.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<style type = "text/css">
body
{
    background-color: black;
    font-color:green;
    color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body onload = "OUTPUT()">      
            <script>
                function OUTPUT()
                {  
                      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                      {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {    
                            <?php                               
                                 echo xmlhttp.responseText;
                            ?>
                        }
                      }
                  xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_access_database.php?",true);
                  xmlhttp.send();
                }
            </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the `ajax_access_database.php`

```
<?php
           echo "<p style = "font-color:red;">Hello World</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using php code inside a html file which would not be processed by your server.

Change the

```
<?php                               
  echo xmlhttp.responseText;
?>
```

to

```
document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Comment: Trying that I get an error `ajax_access_database.php on line 2`? Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, in your php code you're not escaping the double quotation marks correctly. Change `echo "<p style = "font-color:red;">Hello World</p>";` to `echo "<p style=\"font-color:red;\">Hello World</p>";`

Answer (score 1):

In `ajax_access_database.html` you can't echo xmlhttp.responseText because that is a local resource not a server one instead try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type = "text/css">
body
{
    background-color: black;
    font-color:green;
    color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body onload = "OUTPUT()">
            <div id="response"></div>
            <script>
                function OUTPUT()
                {  
                      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                      {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {    
                            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=hr.responseText
                        }
                      }
                  xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_access_database.php?",true);
                  xmlhttp.send();
                  document.getElementById("response").innerHTML="<img src='http://www.vulpusinc.co.nf/loader.gif' />"
                }
            </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works it's just kind of redundant since I could just as well use the DOM to write the `img` tag and append it to the `response` div no?